# rails 6 dynamic bootstrap modal using js.erb error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to display bootstrap modal with dynamically, so every time user click on record it shows modal with that record information. I don't want to show modal for all record every time I reload the page.

I got this error in browser console.
[image]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '==='
```

Controller

```
events_controller.rb

def pay
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
  end
end
```

View

```
index.html.erb

<%= link_to pay_path(id: event.id), remote: true, class: "", method: :patch do %>
  Paid <i class="fe fe-dollar-sign"></i>
<% end %>
```

Pay view

```
    _pay.html.erb

    <!-- Modal: pay invoice -->
    <div class="modal fade show" id="pay_invoice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-vertical" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <!-- Modal body -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js.erb

```
pay.js.erb

document.querySelector("#pay_invoice").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "escape_javascript(<%= render partial: 'pay', locals: {event: @event} %>)");
document.querySelector("#pay_invoice").modal('show');
```

Routes

```
routes.rb

patch "events/:id/pay", to: "events#pay", as: :pay
```

any help?

Comment: In which file and on what line does your browser say the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the ERB tags outwards so that you actually call `escape_javascript`:

```
document.querySelector("#pay_invoice").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterbegin", 
  "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'pay', locals: { event: @event }) %>"
);
```

The reason you are getting a syntax error is that you're outputting the partial unescaped and it contains at least one double quote which ends the string.

Comment: Well it is at least one of the problems with your code. The syntax error could be somewhere else.

Comment: I've just **updated** my question, and you can see where the error shows @max